# How to map IP to hostname when debugging Azure cloud projects

Tags: c#, azure

I have a problem when trying to debug my azure web roles in the azure emulator. I have two cloud projects and a web site, and when debugging them, the load balancer will (of course) assign the cloud projects different public IP-addresses every time.

The projects are interconnected, and since the IPs differ almost every time I hit F5, I have them refer to one another via hostnames and dns. The problem comes when assigning hostnames to these differing IPs.

I have read in an answer to another similar question [Azure Compute Emulator: Is it possible to control the IP of individual instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967902/azure-compute-emulator-is-it-possible-to-control-the-ip-of-individual-instances#16814136) that I could run a startup script in each cloud project to rewrite the hosts-file, but I cannot understand how to actually do it.

Any help? How can I via code access the public IP-adress to the load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

We too had the same problem and to solve it we did the following things:

- **Limit the number of ports used by emulator**: In our case, we also had two services. Open up `DevFC.exe.config` file in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric` and change the settings for `VipPoolStartIPAddress` and `VipPoolEndIPAddress`. Since we had just two services, we set the starting address as `127.0.0.81` and ending address as `127.0.0.82`. This would ensure that the emulator would use only these two IP addresses always. Once you make this change, you have to restart the compute emulator.

  ```
  <add key="VipPoolStartIPAddress" value="127.0.0.81" />
  <add key="VipPoolEndIPAddress" value="127.0.0.82" />
  ```
- **Configure Hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder**: This is where we mapped the IP addresses to our fictitious development domains. This is how the settings look like in our hosts file:

  127.0.0.81  svc1.mydevsite.com #Service 1

  127.0.0.82  svc2.mydevsite.com #Service 2
- **Included `hostHeader` element**: Next step was including `hostHeader` in `Service Definition (.csdef)` file in the cloud project. You have to include `hostHeader` under the `Bindings` section. For Service 1, this is how setting looks like in csdef file:

  <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="svc1.mydevsite.com">

That's pretty much to it as far as settings things are concerned.

There are two limitations with this approach:

1. When you launch the emulator for say service 1, it automatically opens up `http://127.0.0.81:port` and I have go and manually type in `http://svc1.mydevsite.com:port` in the browser.
2. In our scenario, I have to always run service 1 first and then service 2 because of the way IPs are bound in hosts file. Only then `Service 1` is bound to `127.0.0.81` IP address and `Service 2` is bound to `127.0.0.82` IP address. If I start service 2 first, then the emulator assigns it `127.0.0.81` IP Address.

I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish this thing but this is what we ended up doing and so far it has been working well for us (at least for 2 service combination). I'm sure if you start dealing with many cloud projects, this might create some problems.

Comment: This is partly useful information, thanks. I did not know about the DevFC config file, VipPoolStartIPAddress has somewhat made the ip-allocation a little easier to handle for me.

However, I still do not want to having to start each project manually. And since I also code on other projects, I cant limit the Vip-addresses to only two, unfortunately. Therefor, the ip-addresses are still somewhat arbitrary assigned (I do not want to having to restart the emulator between every debug-session).